# How can I use inotify-tools to have an email sent to me when a file in a directory has been added?

Tags: linux, event-handling, inotify, inotify-tools

Users sometimes add files to a directory on a linux server. I was looking at ways to be informed when a file has been added to this directory. I found inotify-tools:

https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/

But I am not too sure how to go about using it. I can't seem to find a proper documentation on it.

I would appreciate it if anyone with experience in it could guide me.

Comment: You could just make that directory read-only, so that users themselves send you emails when they want to put something there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With inotifywait you can do what you want, check the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`entr`](http://entrproject.org/), e.g.

```
while true; do find path/ | entr -d echo Changed | mail foo@example.com; done
```

or:

```
while true; do ls path/* | entr -pd echo Changed | mail foo@example.com; done
```